# How to make anchor tag go to path relative to base site name?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, anchor

So i have this in a django template

```
<a href="challenge/create"> New Challenge </a>
```

When i click it once , i go to

```
http://example.com/SomeOtherThings/challenge/create
```

and if i click it again i go to

```
http://example.com/SomeOtherThings/challenge/challenge/create
```

how do i make it such that each click will go to

```
http://example.com/SomeOtherThings/challenge/create
```

no matter how many times i click it?

Comment: Is that any reason why not using Django url tag ?

Answer (score 0):

this will do it if you can edit the html

```html
<a href="SomeOtherThings/challenge/create">New Challenge</a>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it . , is there i way i get going if i don't really know what `SomeOtherThings` is?